# Firestore realtime listener to multiple documents async await

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am wondering if the realtime listener for Firestore supports `async` `await` instead of promise?

The documentation suggests:

```
var unsubscribe = db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
    var cities = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
       cities.push(doc.data().name);
    });
    console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
});
unsubscribe();
```

Could I write the above realtime listener using `async` `await`? I tried the following and the listener does not work anymore. Also, it won't be possible to detach the listener anymore.

```
var querySnapshot = db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA").onSnapshot
var cities = [];
querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
   cities.push(doc.data().name);
});
console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
```

How could I write it using `async` `await` and would be able to use the detacher as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

async/await (used with promises) doesn't make sense to use with listeners.  A promise represents a unit of work that finishes with a final value, or an error.  A listener is an ongoing process that doesn't finish until the listener is removed using the unsubscribe function.  They are fundamentally different things.

If you want to do a one-time query that gives you a promise that you can await, you should use `get()` instead of `onSnapshot()` as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).  Only use a listener if you want updates to a query as the results change over time.

Comment: Ok, I see. In that case, I cannot use `async` `await` with real-time listeners. Thanks