# Firebase Realtime Database - Set up multiple .on() listeners based on access nodes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am utilising a Firebase Realtime Database with the below structure.
I wish to fetch all "notes" a user has access to and subscribe to changes in those notes.

```
notes: {
  "noteId-1345" : {
    "access" : {
      "author": "1234567890"
        "members": {
          "1234567890": 0 <--- Author
          "0987654321": 1 <--- Member
        }
      },
    "data" : {
      "title": "Hello",
      "content": "Konichiwa!",
      "comment": "123"
    }
  }
}
```

( I am aware this structure could, ideally, be more flat. :) )

To fetch all notes a user has access to - I keep an additional user_notes node in the root:
Whenever I associate a user (update of `members`) with a note, I update both `/notes/$noteid` and `/user_notes/$uid`.

```
user_notes: {
  "$uid": {
    "noteId-1345": {
      myHide: false,
      mySortOrder: 0,
      title: "Hello"
    }
  }
}
```

When fetching data I wish to set up subscription to all notes the user has access to.

I begin by fetching the ids for notes the user has access to and then attach listeners to subscribe to updates in each `note`.

```
const uid = getState().auth.uid
let collectedNotes = {} 
...
database.ref(`user_notes/${uid}`).on('value', (myAccessSnaps) => {
  myAccessSnaps.forEach((accessSnap) => {
    const noteId = accessSnap.key
    const privateData = {'personalData': {...accessSnap.val()}}
    database.ref(`notes/${noteId}`).on('value', (noteSnap)=>{
      const notData = noteSnap.val()
      const fullData = { ...privateData, ...notData }
      const note = {
        id: noteSnap.key,
        ...fullData
      }
      collectedNotes[note.id] = note
      ...
    })
  }))
})
```

(Of course, I will need to use `.off()` to detach listeners before setting up new ones)

This is somewhat problematic since I have to attach one listener per `note` - and there could be hundreds of notes in the database.
Is this the most efficient approach? - It seems inefficient.

Is there a way to listen to **ALL** the notes a user has acess to in the `/notes` path with **one** listener? Or is my approaching altogether wrong? :)

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding that [.on() does not return a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63350415/firestore-realtime-listener-to-multiple-documents-async-await) - I became much easier to solve my problem.

Attaching a lot of `.on()` listeners did not make any sense to me.

The easiest approach for me was to:

1 - Update my access nodes with a time stamp `updatedAt` each time a note was updated

2 - Load initial data using `.once()` that returns promise,see code below.

3 - Set up separate subscription for when access nodes changes

```
let myPromises = []
database.ref(`user_notes/${uid}`).once('value', (myAccessSnaps) => {
  myAccessSnaps.forEach((accessSnap) => {
    const noteId = accessSnap.key
    const privateData = {'personalData': {...accessSnap.val()}}
    myPromises.push(
      database.ref(`notes/${noteId}`).once('value', (noteSnap)=>{
        const notData = noteSnap.val()
        const fullData = { ...privateData, ...notData }
        const note = {
          id: noteSnap.key,
          ...fullData
        }
        collectedNotes[note.id] = note
        ...
      })
    )
  }))
})

return Promise.all(myPromises)
.then(() => {
  dispatch(setNotes(categories))
...
// Set up subscription after initial load
database.ref(`user_notes/${uid}`).on('value', (myAccessSnaps) => {
  ...
  // Use access node listener only - gets updated by 'updatedAt'
  database.ref(`notes/${noteId}`).once('value', (noteSnap)=>{
    //Collect and dispatch data
```

Kind regards /K